# Does a user have to log in to run a process and become its owner?

Tags: linux, process, users, root

In general, does a user have to log in to run a process and become its owner (ruid, or euid)? Does this apply to  any user or any non-root user?
For example:

- In the boot sequence of Linux, the kernel starts the init system as the first process, and then the init process runs `login` so that each user can login.
  The init process is owned by `root`, and does  the user `root` have to log in before starting the `init` process? See [Why is there a `systemd` process owned by each user that is logged in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489907/why-is-there-a-systemd-process-owned-by-each-user-that-is-logged-in)
- When using `ssh` to run a command without starting an interactive shell, do we have to log in first  or not to run the command?

[If I don't need to log in to run a process as its owner, how can I do that?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489924/how-can-i-run-a-process-as-its-owner-without-logging-in)

Thanks.

Comment: When you SSH into a machine, you provide credentials (either by password or public key) to prove that you have adequate access right to the system as the user that you say you are. This constitutes a logging in. As for the first question, do you know the difference between a service account and an account for an interactive user? See e.g. [What is the difference between user and service account?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/314725)

Comment: Thanks. How can a service user start a process as its owner or become its owner later?

Comment: What do you mean by "owner" in this context?  A process runs under a uid, has a primary gid, a set of secondary gids, potentially a set of capabilities.  There is a parent process (which may be `init` or another process) and there may be some child processes.  I'm not sure what you mean by "owner"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don’t need to log in to start a process running as a given user. Logging in is a user-space construct; the kernel doesn’t care about that. There are multiple examples of this; for example, cron jobs can run as any user, without that user being logged in.

To address your specific questions:

- no, root doesn’t need to log in to start the `init` process, thankfully (imagine handling a fleet of thousands of servers and millions of VMs otherwise);
- connecting using SSH counts as logging in.

Comment: Thanks. If I want run a process as its owner without logging in, how can I do that? Is the only way to call setuid() or seteuid() in the program run by the process?

Comment: That’s another question.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "logging in"? That has led to several other questions.